# RadNumericTextBox disable spinbuttons using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I got a `RadNumericTextBox` with the attribute `showSpinButtons` set to `true`, the textfield itself is readonly and it's updated by using the spinbuttons.

but I want those spinbuttons to be disabled and enabled whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked.

OR

hiding the spinbuttons by setting the `set_showSpinButtons` attribute to false with JS is also fine.

but I can't seem to manage both, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox2" runat="server" MinValue="1" MaxValue="100" MaxLength="3" 
 ShowSpinButtons="True">
   <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" ZeroPattern="n" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

my javascript:

```
RadNumericTextBox1.set_showSpinButtons(false); //trying everything at this point
RadNumericTextBox2.SpinUpButton.disabled = true;
RadNumericTextBox2.SpinDownButton.disabled = true;
RadNumericTextBox2.SpinUpButton.enabled = false;
RadNumericTextBox2.SpinDownButton.enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing `RadNumericTextBox1.disable();`